# Average values of all weeks

Tags: mysql, sql, date

My table:

```
id - value - time    
0  - 15    - 21.09.13    
1  - 22    - 22.09.13    
2  - 11    - 23.09.13    
3  - 17    - 24.09.13
...
```

I want to get average values from last week. But not for only one. I need average values of all weeks.
I was trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT AVG(value) 
FROM table 
WHERE time BETWEEN date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 8 DAY) AND NOW();
```

But it returns only one row.
It should return something like this:

```
AVG(value)
25 //first week    
23.6 //second    
21
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group the data for every week. You could use [yearweek()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek)

```
SELECT yearweek(`time`), AVG(value) 
FROM table 
WHERE time BETWEEN date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 8 DAY) AND NOW()
group by yearweek(`time`)
```

Comment: What DB are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, ...?